# linear system:3 variables, differential equtation, 3 points on one straignt line

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

At the initial moment of time, three points were on one straight line. The trajectories of the points are described by a system of equations. The question is can these points again appear on one straight line after some period of time?
$$\dot{x} = Ax$$, where $A$ is $3\times3$ matrix with with constant coefficients
 and
$ x=x(t)=\left(\begin{array}{crl}
x_1(t)\\
x_2(t)\\
x_3(t)
\end{array}\right)$
I know that $$x(t) = e^{tA}C$$ and if $x(0)=\left(\begin{array}{crl}
x_1^0\\
x_2^0\\
x_3^0
\end{array}\right)$ then $x(t) = e^{tA}\left(\begin{array}{crl}
x_1^0\\
x_2^0\\
x_3^0
\end{array}\right)$How can i continue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x_0$ is normal eigenvector of $A$, yes. These are called mode excitation of a linear system. If your initial condition is an eigenvector, then the solution is going to remain on the line $kx_0$ where $k \in R$. If $x_0$ is $i^{th}$ eigenvector $v_i$ and $\lambda_i$ is the corresponding eigenvalue, then we have:

\begin{equation*}
x(t) = e^{At}x_0 = e^{At}v_i = \sum_{0}^{\infty}\frac{(At)^n}{n!}v_i = \sum_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^n}{n!}A^nv_i = \sum_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^n}{n!}\lambda_i^nv_i = e^{\lambda_i t}v_i = e^{\lambda_i t}x_0. 
\end{equation*}

Note that $e^{\lambda_i t}$ is scalar, and $x(t)$ remains on the direction of $x_0$.

Comment: Why is $e^{\lambda_it}$ scalar?

Comment: Scalar means not a vector, just a number. $\lambda_i t$ is scalar, and so is its exponential.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: Glad to help...